# R furrr: authenticate an API on each future process before running the computation

Tags: r, r-future, furrr

I am running a parallel computation using `furrr` in R. The computation require access to a web API and an authentication needs to take place. If I run a parallel process, each process needs to authenticate.
In the below, I have 6 processes. So I would need to authenticate on these six processes first then run the calculations. I don't know how to do that using `furrr`. So I end up doing an authentication in each run, which is really inefficient.

Below is a simple example for illustrative purposes. It does not work because I can't share the `api.configure` function, but hopefully you get the idea.

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
library(furrr)
plan(multiprocess, workers = 6)

testdf =  starwars %>%
  select(-films, -vehicles, -starships) %>%
  future_pmap_dfr(.f = function(...){
    api.configure(username = "username", password = "password")
    currentrow = tibble(...)
    l = tibble(name = currentrow$name, height = currentrow$height)
    return(l)
})
```

Comment: Could the API connection be kept as [global](https://rdrr.io/cran/furrr/man/future_options.html)?

Comment: I don't know. is there something I can do for that or is this an API specific thing?

Comment: if api.configure returns a connection object, you could pass this connection object as global variable.

Comment: The api does not return an explicit connection object. it uses env to store token and other parameters. So I am now looking if I can use the api::api.env object in global

Comment: I did `future_options(globals = "api:::api.env")` but that failed giving:
`Error in api.authenticate() : Missing required parameter: username`

Comment: See if my answer works : if not I'll delete it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222229/discussion-between-courvoisier-and-waldi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this was to ask the dev of the API to add variable in the API package that tests whether the connection is open or not. this way I authenticate once on each of the `future` processes, if the connection is not open, and once this is done, all subsequent API authentication calls to that process will be halted by the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the connexion before the map:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(furrr)
plan(multiprocess, workers = 6)

future_options(globals = T) # this should be the default
api.configure(username = "username", password = "password")
ls(all=TRUE) #Check if new environment variables are available to save connexion

testdf =  starwars %>%
  select(-films, -vehicles, -starships) %>%
  future_pmap_dfr(.f = function(...){
    
    currentrow = tibble(...)
    l = tibble(name = currentrow$name, height = currentrow$height)
    return(l)
})
```

Comment: the environment variable `api:::api.env` is not in the list. Furthermore, we changed the API to output the hidden env variable, it didn't change anything.

Comment: How does the API store its connexion? For a DB it would be for example `conn <- dbConnect(user,pwd,...)`. future_map works well with a single db connexion and multiple tasks. So the connexion object is the key, making multiple connexions isn't always mandatory.

Comment: The API stores the connection in the package environment variable, which is a hidden variable. Also, all API calls do not have an explicit connection object as input.